# WidgetKit - macOS don't run IntentHandler

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, sirikit, widgetkit

Hi I have same code for IntentHandler for iOS and macOS. On iOS works perfectly on macOS not at all. In WidgetKit simulator I even see option to configure the widget so it load the `.intentdefinition` file.
I also checked that IntentHandler and all required files (CoreData model etc) are in the target for both macOS, widget and Intent.
When try to edit the Widget I get - `No options were provided for this parameter`. Also I tried to remove all same App from macOs, cleaned Derived data.

I recreate the same issue I have with Apple Demo project Fruta and the repo is here: https://github.com/kmentrobin/Fruta-macOS-Widget. It already has Intents and all requirements in `FavoriteSmoothieWidget` which should allow the user to select their favorite Smoothie :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in `.intentdefinition` where is needed for macOS to have **Checked** value `Siri can ask for value when run`. Don't know why but that only helped. If you want to play around with that is still on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

In `Intent` target check `Intent.entitlements` file for containing this key/value:

```xml
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
```